# How to create a filter for columns in a dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table which looks like this

```
id  login_id     trend_type sep oct nov
 1   abc@abc.com  Billing    10  34  43
 1   abc@abc.com  Visits     20  43  56
 1   abc@abc.com  Revenue    30  12  12
 1   pqr@pqr.com  Billing    40  23  54
 1   pqr@pqr.com  Visits     50  21  47
 1   pqr@pqr.com  Revenue    60  98  12
```

I want to create a dashboard where I can display graphs of all these Trend Types and add a filter for the user so they can select the month for which they want to view the graphs.

I have tried this solution -
https://community.tableau.com/thread/228965
but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tableau really likes data that is taller rather than wider.  In this case, you need to do a PIVOT on the month data.  A pivot will create a column for the months and another column for the values.  Your data will have more rows now but fewer columns.

When you bring the data into Tableau, on the Data Source screen, highlight the three month columns and select pivot.

[image: Pivot]

You can also change the name of the Pivot Field Names (to Month) and Pivot Field Values (to Amount or another appropriate name).

[image: Rename]

Click on the orange Sheet 1 on the bottom left.  Next, create a calculated field to create a full date.  (Tableau doesn't know what 'sep' is.)

[image: Calculated Field]

```
[Pivot Field Names] + "-01-2019"
```

This field just creates a string that Tableau can parse (eg 'sep-01-2019').  Now tell Tableau it is a Date field by changing the field type (click on the Abc next to the Dimension name).

[image: Change field type]

At this point, you can create a viz and add filters.  Here is an example.

[image: Final viz]